# Converting String values to xml

Tags: iphone

I have some string values that are retrieved from json data. I need a process of converting this strings to xml format and Post it to a url

Answer (score 0):

If it's inside iPhone SDK you will have to parse the string to convert it to XML, unless you can just post the xml **as-is**.

Anyway. To parse the XML, you have basically two easy options:

1. NSXMLParser
2. libxml2 (my preferred choice, don't know why)

Then you can use NSURLConnection class to post the information to the desired XML. There are a lot of Stackoverflow questions already covering this issue you can search and use.

You can also look at an example [here](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=689884).